# Hourly Popup window with text input in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, timer, popup, submit

I am trying to make an application that pops up a window every hour and allows me to input some text and submit.

This text will be saved to a text file for now, but a database later.

How do I make something popup every hour and have text input?

It needs to run on XP and Win7.

Many thanks
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows has a scheduler, or you could make an application with a notification icon and just show the window when the current time is an hour later then the previous popup time.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565

Answer (score 2):

You can use the System.Windows.Forms.Timer class:

```
Timer timer = new Timer {Interval = 1500}; // Interval is miliseconds
timer.Tick += (s,e) => MessageBox.Show("Timer Expired");
timer.Start();
```